# What are the bare minimum system requirements to run npm and node on Ubuntu?

Tags: node.js, npm

I would like to run a very bare-bones node.js web server (mostly as a proof of concept) on an AWS EC2 Linux (Ubuntu) instance.  It would just query a database and return a small (a few kB at most) response, handling on average maybe one request per minute.  I can't find anything about the absolute minimum requirements to run node and npm.  I assume a single cpu is fine, so I guess I'm mainly concerned about RAM - what's the minimum require to run node and npm?

Comment: This is old but probably still useful: https://www.tomspencer.dev/blog/2016/10/01/running-a-node-dot-js-app-in-a-low-memory-environment/